# Inject stateful EJB beans in a maven project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I don't understand one thing that I hope someone of you could explain me. I have a maven enterprise project developed with glassfish.

I use the insert code netbeans function (right click) to call bean in a servlet and in particular the annotation

```
@EJB
```

I don't understand why when I call a stateful session bean through Insert Code function in netbeans the bean is called through JNDI. Here what I mean

```
private BookingBeanInterface lookupBookingBeanLocal() {
        try {
            Context c = new InitialContext();
            return (BookingBeanInterface) c.lookup("java:global/it.volaconnoi_volaconnoi-webapp-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/it.volaconnoi_volaconnoi-webapp-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/BookingBean!it.volaconnoi.logic.BookingBeanInterface");
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
            throw new RuntimeException(ne);
        }
    }`
```

The above function hasn't been wrote by me

I can't inject a stateful session bean through EJB?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the problem:

As you probably already know a single Servlet instance is used to handle multiple requests from multiple clients so the Stateful EJB should not be injected directly in the Servlet and kept as an instance property, or we will face obvious thread-safety related issues. In our case we are fetching it from JNDI inside doGet method and storing it in the HTTP session so each user will have it's own Sateful EJB instance.